# How to REBIND all the UDF and Procedures existing in a determined Schema in IBM System i V7R1?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

After upgrade our IBM System i from V5R4 to V7R1, most of our UDFs and Procedures doesn’t work. I’ve redeployed some of them running the CREATE script and works again.

There’s any way to REBIND all the UDF and Procedures existing in a determined Schema?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did this upgrade last September and all of my UDFs and all of my stored procedures work fine.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Executing a Procedure I'm getting this error: 

[SQL0204] F_GET00007 in LMSCHEMA type *SRVPGM not found. Run of routine failed. - Roll back completed successfully. 

(F_GET00007 is a Function called F_GET_FIXING)

Comment: If you do a DSPSRVPGM LMSCHEMA/F_GET00007 do you see it?  If so, call IBM for software support and tell them about it.  There may be a database cross reference problem they can help you with.  If you don't see it in LMSCHEMA, then it seems your library structure has changed somehow.  Is the user library list different now?